# File downloaded could not be played

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, download

I could not play the file "ARROW.mp4" what could be wrong ?
While trying to play the file with my video player it kept saying that it could not render the file.

```
#Opened the file to store the file.
f1 = open("ARROW.mp4","wb")

import urllib.request
#opened the page containing the file
myVideo = urllib.request.urlopen('http://o2tvseries.com/download/18454')
currentSizeOfFile = 0
#downloaded the file in the loop
while True:
    party = myVideo.read(1000000)
    if len(party) < 1 : break
    currentSizeOfFile += len(party)
    f1.write(party)
    print(currentSizeOfFile,' copied\n')
#closed the file.
f1.close()
```